# Ebean inner Join on self table

Tags: java, playframework, inner-join, ebean

Is there a way to get partial object tree on child objects with parent child structure so I can achive:

```
select distinct * from kb_event t0   inner join kb_event  t1 on t1.parent_id = t0.id  where t1.status = -1;
```

My eban query

```
Ebean.getServer("default").find(EventModel.class)
    .select("children.id, name, status").fetch("children")
            .where()
            .eq("children.status", -1)
            .findList();
```

Returns parent element but with all children listed under children node.

My model looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kb_event")
public class EventModel extends Model implements Bean {

@Id
@JsonProperty("eventId")
Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  mappedBy = "parent")
public List<EventModel> children;

@ManyToOne
public EventModel parent;
}
```

with proper foreign key on parent Id